# Finding all dates after a date for a variable number of days

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, date

I have a list of dates in a table.  For this examples the 1st day of each month.  Let's call it table timeperiod with column endTime

```
endTime
1-1-2019
2-1-2019
3-1-2019
4-1-2019
```

I want to find all dates x number of days after each date in a list.  Lets say x = 4.  Then the list should be:

```
1-1-2019
1-2-2019
1-3-2019
1-4-2019
2-1-2019
2-2-2019
2-3-2019
2-4-2019
3-1-2019
3-2-2019
3-3-2019
3-4-2019
4-1-2019
4-2-2019
4-3-2019
4-4-2019
```

I have found solutions to find all dates between dates but I keep getting *"Subquery returned more than 1 value"* error when I try to use it with a list of dates.

Here is an example of something I tried but doesn't work

```
declare @days DECIMAL = 4
declare @StartDate date = (select convert(varchar, DATEADD(Day, +0, endTime),101) from timeperiod
declare @EndDate date = (select convert(varchar, DATEADD(Day, +@days, endTime),101) from timeperiod;

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,myDate) as myDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,myDate) <=  @EndDate
)
SELECT myDate
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: You tag the question as MySQL-relative, but use SQL Server syntax... strange...

Comment: Tag your version of sqlserver too please; it can have a bearing

Answer (score 2):

Here is a row generator that generates 5 rows, 0 to 4:

```
WITH rg AS (
   SELECT 0 AS rn
   UNION ALL
   SELECT rg.rn + 1
   FROM   rg
   WHERE  rn < 4
)
```

Here we join it with your existing table that has firsts of the month and use DATEADD to add `rn` numbers of days (between 0 and 4) to the endPeriod. CROSS JOINing it caused the rows in timePeriod to repeat 5 times each:

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(DAY, rg.rn, timePeriod.endTime) as fakeEndTime
FROM
  rg CROSS JOIN timePeriod
```

I wasn't really clear when you say "days X days after the date, say x = 4" - to me if there is a day that is 1-Jan-2000, then the date 4 days after this is 5-Jan-2000

If you only want the 1,2,3 and 4 of Jan make the row generator `< 3` instead of `< 4`

Answer (score 0):

Already +1'd on Caius Jard's recursive cte.

Here is yet another option using an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a CROSS JOIN

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([endTime] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1-1-2019')
,('2-1-2019')
,('3-1-2019')
,('4-1-2019')

Select NewDate = dateadd(DAY,N-1,EndTime)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Join ( 
                Select Top (4) N=row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
                 From  master..spt_values N1
            ) B
```

**Returns**

```
NewDate
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
2019-01-04
2019-02-01
2019-02-02
2019-02-03
2019-02-04
2019-03-01
2019-03-02
2019-03-03
2019-03-04
2019-04-01
2019-04-02
2019-04-03
2019-04-04
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that spt_values doesn't exits on SQLAzure, and some other "table with N rows" will be needed. Of course, it's always a fairly good idea to have a calendar/numbers table kicking around anyway, for those tricky queries like "Mondays, Tuesdays and Thursdays but not national holidays"!